# Process 'Gradle Test Executor' finished with non-zero exit value 29

Tags: java, gradle

One of my test tasks fails without any apparent error message in any log:

:midonet-cluster:test FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':midonet-cluster:test'.

> Process 'Gradle Test Executor 12' finished with non-zero exit value 29

Here is the stacktrace:

> org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':midonet-cluster:test'.                                                                                                                                                                        [17/1998]
>           at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:98)
>           at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:68)
>           at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:62)
>           at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
>           at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:88)
>           at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:46)
>           at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:51)
>           at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
>           at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
>           at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
>           at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:236)
>           at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:228)
>           at org.gradle.internal.Transformers$4.transform(Transformers.java:169)
>           at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:106)
>           at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:61)
>           at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:228)
>           at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:215)
>           at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:77)
>           at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:58)
>           at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:32)
>           at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:113)
>           at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:37)
>           at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
>           at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$000(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
>           at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$1.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:43)
>           at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
>           at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
>           at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:30)
>           at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$RunTasksAction.execute(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:230)
>           at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$RunTasksAction.execute(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:227)
>           at org.gradle.internal.Transformers$4.transform(Transformers.java:169)
>           at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:106)
>           at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:56)
>           at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:161)
>           at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:112)
>           at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:95)
>           at org.gradle.launcher.exec.GradleBuildController.run(GradleBuildController.java:66)
>           at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ExecuteBuildActionRunner.run(ExecuteBuildActionRunner.java:28)
>           at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
>           at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:41)
>           at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:26)
>           at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:75)
>           at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:49)
>           at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:49)
>           at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:31)
>           at org.gradle.launcher.cli.RunBuildAction.run(RunBuildAction.java:51)
>           at org.gradle.internal.Actions$RunnableActionAdapter.execute(Actions.java:173)
>           at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:281)
>           at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:254)
>           at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:33)
>           at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:24)
>           at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:33)
>           at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:22)
>           at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:247)
>           at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:182)
>           at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:33)
>           at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:45)
>           at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:60)
>           at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:37)
>           at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:23)
>           at org.gradle.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start(BootstrapMainStarter.java:30)
>           at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:127)
>           at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:56)
>
> Caused by: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'Gradle Test Executor 11' finished with non-zero exit value 29
>           at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle$ExecResultImpl.assertNormalExitValue(DefaultExecHandle.java:369)
>           at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.DefaultWorkerProcess.waitForStop(DefaultWorkerProcess.java:190)
>           at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.DefaultWorkerProcessBuilder$MemoryRequestingWorkerProcess.waitForStop(DefaultWorkerProcessBuilder.java:228)
>           at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.ForkingTestClassProcessor.stop(ForkingTestClassProcessor.java:122)
>           at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.processors.RestartEveryNTestClassProcessor.endBatch(RestartEveryNTestClassProcessor.java:63)
>           at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.processors.RestartEveryNTestClassProcessor.stop(RestartEveryNTestClassProcessor.java:57)
>           at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
>           at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
>           at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.FailureHandlingDispatch.dispatch(FailureHandlingDispatch.java:29)
>           at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.AsyncDispatch.dispatchMessages(AsyncDispatch.java:132)
>           at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.AsyncDispatch.access$000(AsyncDispatch.java:33)
>           at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.AsyncDispatch$1.run(AsyncDispatch.java:72)
>           at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
>           at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:46)

There are no failed tests.

This seems to be some resources issue since the problem disappear when I reduce the number of tests (by excluding packages from test Task). Which tests are excluded does not really matter.

The issue is still there if gradle daemon is disabled.

Gradel version is 3.5.1 but the issue is still there with 4.5.1.

Running task in debug mode does not show anything new. We can check that the failed process moved to "STARTED" state and then to "FAILED" state.

This is happens always on ubuntu16.04 machine with 80GB of RAM and sometimes on my MAC with 16GB of RAM.

Any help how to solve or debug this would be greatly appreciated!

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

It turned out to be a System.exit() called by main code since some tests did not close backend service. I believe gradle might handle this better :)